# using tFTPConnection to connect to SFTP using a public key file without passphrase

Tags: sftp, talend, public-key, passphrase

I am using tFTPConnection to connect to SFTP using a public key file.
But the issue with this component is that I can't leave Password and Key Passphrase blank as it throws error.
But when I tryusing Filezilla, I am able to connect.
Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're configuring this component and the actual error that you're getting.

Comment: Sorry For less info provided..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by blank actually not filling the field, this won't work. But you can provide an empty string `""` so that an empty string will be transmitted.

*NOTE:* I needed to guess this because there is no picture of the configuration at the point of answering.

Comment: Thanks #tobi6 ....  I was not providing anything but when I provided  emty string with quotes, it worked !

Answer (score 1):

you can not pass the blank or empty field while configuration, this will through error for sure. In any case if you have to pass with blank field put " " there so that it can be taken as empty string.
Or you can use username and password as talend. 
Try more to describe your job design and configuration for clear view.